# How to get current state value inside websocket onmessage?

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I'm building a website with react(Next.js) and websocket like below.

```js
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null)
const ws = useRef()

useEffect(() => {
  ws.current = new WebSocket(...)

  ws.current.onopen = () => {...}

  ws.current.onmessage = event => {
      console.log(selectedId)
  }

  ...

}, [selectedId])
```

Inside onmessage, console always returns same value even user set other value with setSelectedId.
I know that when websocket initialized, it will return initial value. But I need to get current state inside onmessage. Is there a solution on this? Or is it the only way to reconnect websocket to get changed state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `useEffect` runs after the component has first mounted and keeps the initial value of `selectedId` in a closure which it returns on every message. To update this based on the value of `selectedId` you can add another effect like

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(ws.current)
        ws.current.onmessage = () => console.log(selectedId)
}, [selectedId])
```

which replaces the old event handler with one that uses the updated value of `selectedId`.